# WCF - Object as known type -> interoperable?

Tags: c#, wcf, object, interop, known-types

Actually there should be a straight forward answer to this question (is about the "Object" property below):

Having the following data contract:

```
    [KnownType(typeof(bool))]
    [KnownType(typeof(int))]
    [KnownType(typeof(string))]
    [KnownType(typeof(Customer))]
    [KnownType(typeof(Client))]
    public class Transaction
    {    
        // properties
        [DataMember(Name = "UID")]
        public int UID{}

        [DataMember(Name = "Type")]
        public Enums.TransactionType Type{}

        [DataMember(Name = "Data")]
        public Object Data{}
    }
```

and the following service contract:

```
public interface IService
{
      [OperationContract(Name = "GetData")]
      List<Transaction> GetTransact();
}
```

Will this be interoperable? Saying from Java, gSoap? If not, how can I make it interoperable?

Thank you.

**EDIT:**
I just want to know if WCF knows how to serialize/deserialize the Object from/into the known types defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be fine as long as the client can generate the types properly from the WSDL. For example depending on the client, it might change C#'s `List<Transaction>` into a `Transaction[]` or something fairly equivalent. You will also need to select the right binding type. Usually basicHttpBinding has the best results for interoperability.

Comment: yeah, this is clear... But I just want to know if WCF knows how to serialize/deserialize from Object using the known types defined.

Comment: Things added as a [KnownType] are there to tell the serializer about them, and also adds them to the WSDL.  If the serializer gets an Object, then yes it will scan the KnownTypes for one that fits. Typically this comes into play with inheritance more than anything.

Comment: Also, sorry, I didn't notice the first time I looked at this that one of your data members was of type `Object`. In this case, I would expect WCF to handle the Object `Data` field fine as long as the actual instance is of type `Customer` or `Client`.  On serialization it would know from the instance type, on deserialization it would know from the type name passed in the SOAP message.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer... I will start go for it. As soon as it works I will accept your answer :) Btw I started this question when I saw the MS "WCF Test Client" app reporting errors to my function because of the returning "Object"