# Is it possible to use object in web service?

Tags: c#, web-services, generics, svc

enter code hereI would like to send dynamic type with .asvc web service. I have one class with some properties. I would like to send any kind of object even class in this list. And cast back on client side.

I mean I always want to use `SysResult` type. But sometimes with `List<Apple>`, sometimes `List<Orrange>`

Like bellow

```
    [Serializable]
    public class SysResult
    {
        public int CRCResult;
        public long CRCTransactionId;
        public bool CRCStatus;
        public string CRCMessage;
        public List<Anything> ListObject;
    }
```

I've tried to use `object[]`, `Array`, `List<object>`, `dynamic` etc. But I am getting this error.
"The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly."

By the way for all non-specific object types service referance class represents `object[]` type.

```
  [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(IsRequired=true)]
        public object[] ListObject {
            get {
                return this.ListObjectField;
            }
            set {
                if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.ListObjectField, value) != true)) {
                    this.ListObjectField = value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged("ListObject");
                }
            }
        }
```

Is there any way to send dynamic type? Or am I trying to do something totally wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return a known type . It can't return just "object" or even an interface. How would wcf know what to serialize the object into on the client if there is no datacontract?

> Normally, when passing parameters and return values between a client
>   and a service, both endpoints share all of the data contracts of the
>   data to be transmitted. However, this is not the case in the following
>   circumstances:
>
> ...
>   The declared type for the information to be transmitted is Object.
>   Because every type inherits from Object, and it cannot be known in
>   advance which type is actually sent, the receiving endpoint cannot
>   determine in advance the data contract for the transmitted data.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167(v=vs.110).aspx

Also

You could use KnownTypes to map your Interfaces and Objects. Look at this links:
[WCF - Object as known type -> interoperable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980121/wcf-object-as-known-type-interoperable)
[WCF, Interface return type and KnownTypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108076/wcf-interface-return-type-and-knowntypes)

Answer (score 1):

This might give you some help in the matter at hand

> WCF does not support the use of generic methods for service operation.
>   In other words, only concrete types can be used for service
>   operations.  Open generic types cannot be used.  Now, it is important
>   to clarify this is not a limitation of WCF.  Rather, it is a
>   limitation of WSDL, which is used to expose service metadata to
>   consumers.  There is no construct within WSDL to define a generic
>   type.  Generally speaking, I agree with this behavior since it
>   decreases the coupling between a client and service.
>
> Although generic methods are not supported, it is possible to expose
>   generic objects for the purpose of exchanging data.  However, there
>   are some limitations.  Let's take a closer look:

http://jeffbarnes.net/blog/post/2007/05/10/WCF-Serialization-and-Generics.aspx